# How to rename all variables in SAS?

Tags: sas, stata

I am trying to change Stata code to SAS. In Stata I rename all variables using

```
rename *_* **
```

How can I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do is using dictionary tables and code and explanation is in SAS documentation shown below.

http://support.sas.com/kb/48/674.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the naming structure and conventions but in general you can rename using the RENAME statement or data set option.
Rename statement:

```
rename old_variable_name = new_variable_name;
```

Rename option:

```
set sashelp.class (rename = (age = age_years));
```

If your variables are indexed and have a common prefix you can rename multiple variables at once:

```
rename old1-old20 = new1-new20;
```